# C# Check which Parameters are set in an Named-Method

Tags: c#, methods

I hope someone can help me or give me an information if that is even possible...

I want to check in an Named-Method which parameters are really set and passed to it.
It would be possible to make an Dictionary and pass the parameter by an KeyValue-Pair to the Method, but is there an other solution?

Can i check the current method in the stack-trace and collect the current set argmuents of that method or something?

For better understanding, i created an example to visualize the issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass newC = new TestClass("Init", 10);
        newC.ToString();    //{varStr: "Init"; varInt: 10}

        newC.update(vStr: "ok");

        newC.ToString();    //{varStr: "ok"; varInt: 0}     
                            // !!! but should have {varStr: "ok"; varInt: 10} !!!
        Console.WriteLine("<-- press any key to exit -->");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    string varStr;
    int varInt;

    public TestClass(string vStr, int vInt)
    {
        varStr = vStr;
        varInt = vInt;
    }

    public void update(string vStr = default, int vInt = default)
    {
        //here check it if vStr-Param was set and set varStr only if it was passed to it!
        //TODO
        varStr = vStr;
        //here check it if vInt-Param was set and set varInt only if it was passed to it!
        //TODO
        varInt = vInt;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"TestClass: varStr: {varStr}; varInt: {varInt};");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this, like the way i think?

**EDIT:**

*Use default value and check it!*

> The default value can also be set over this Method! So an solution
> with checking the default value and only if that is equal than we set
> the value, is no option for us.
>
> We have also an "custom-class" which we give over that method and it
> could also be nullable.

*Use Overload methods!*

> The Problem is that this class has not 2 variables, it has over 15 and
> it would be an big overhead to write each overload method.

**SOLUTION:**

I found a Solution without declare default values... so every Value is able to be set!

```
    class TestClass
{
    string varStr;
    int varInt;
    TestClass1 varCustomClass;

    public TestClass(string vStr, int vInt, TestClass1 vCustomClass)
    {
        varStr = vStr;
        varInt = vInt;
        varCustomClass = vCustomClass;
    }

    public void update(Opt<int> varInt = default(Opt<int>),
                       Opt<string> varStr = default(Opt<string>),
                       Opt<TestClass1> varCustomClass = default(Opt<TestClass1>))
    {
        if (varStr.HasValue)
        {
            this.varStr = varStr.Value;
        }
        if (varInt.HasValue)
        {
            this.varInt = varInt.Value;
        }
        if (varCustomClass.HasValue)
        {
            this.varCustomClass = varCustomClass.Value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"TestClass3: varStr: {varStr}; varInt: {varInt}; varCustomClass: {varCustomClass};");
        return null;
    }
}

public struct Opt<T>
{
    public Opt(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = true;
    }

    public static explicit operator T(Opt<T> optional)
    {
        return optional._value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Opt<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Opt<T>(value);
    }

    T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    bool _hasValue;
    public bool HasValue
    {
        get { return _hasValue; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(vStr != default(string))`?

Comment: Use overloads instead of optional parameters.

Comment: `if (vStr != default(string))`. Beware that the default of `string` (and any other reference type) is `null`, but the default of `int` (and any other value type) is an actual value. I.E `default(int) == 0` is true

Comment: just check if your variable has the default-value and if not assign the new value.

Comment: Maybe with overload methods

Comment: But we have the issue that we also use "null" for an String and it is possible that also the Integer-Variable can get any value ... also the value 0.

Answer (score 1):

Might your string also be null? If not, you can check if it's null. For your int, you can use a nullable value type:

```
public void update(string vStr = null, int? vInt = null)
    {
        if(vStr != null)
        {
             varStr = vStr;
        }
        if(vInt != null)
        {
            varInt = vInt.Value;
        }
    }
```

If you have only a few parameters and they all have different types, overloaded methods are also a good solution:

```
public void update(string vStr)
 {
 varStr = vStr;
 }

public void update(int vInt)
 {
 varInt = vInt;
 }

public void update(string vStr, int vInt)
 {
 update(vStr);
 update(vInt);
 }
```